# openerp-server goes down, and stops functioning

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-server

I've installed Odoo/OpnnERP, and I've put the openerp-server daemon in /etc/init.d to get it started automatically on Ubuntu startup. It gets started normally on every reboot and works fine. But sometimes it goes down automatically, I don't know any pattern when it goes down, and I also can't see any reason in the log file (/var/log/openerp/openerp-server.log). It just goes down without any logs. When I find it down, I have to reboot manually to get it started again.

Any help on spotting the issue which causes openerp-server to stop automatically without any logs?

Thanks,
Abdul

Comment: Check cron. Set the log to verbose. Wait and analyze.

Comment: Thanks @Markus. How to "set log to verbose", and what cron to check specifically?

Comment: The logging of your openerp. Read it's docs. I am not familiar with it, that is just basic sysadmin's advice. As for the crons: All system crons ;). Oh, and btw, better ask this on http://superuser.com - SO is dedicated to _programming_ questions, in a strict sense.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the advice superuser.com ;) I'll ask there, and check all system crons ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just found an answer to the above issue. Here is the [solution](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/openerp-server-stops-and-goes-down-without-logs-67196)

Comment: I'm facing the same problem and 1GB of RAM isn't enough. Even the Swap file is enough, still going down automatically. I don't see a huge usage of the VM in the usage graph, so it may be an fatal error that's triggering the issue. Pretty bad application, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I have Odoo under a DO droplet and all I did was upgrading the droplet, that's it!